# spring rest access in outside of application without login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

I have one application using spring 4 and all the methods are rest(using RestController).  I used spring-security(role based) for login and authentication url.

Below is my spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/public/login"
            default-target-url="/auth/userhome" authentication-failure-url="/public/fail2login" always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/public/logout" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" access="fullyAuthenticated" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

        <security:session-management
            session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" invalid-session-url="/login">
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" />
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="hbUserDetailService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Service:

```
package com.arat.budget.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.arat.budget.dao.UserDao;
import com.arat.budget.model.UserRoles;
import com.arat.budget.model.Users;

    @Service
    public class HbUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
        @Autowired
        private UserDao userDao;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Transactional
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

            Users user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRoleses());

            return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

        }

        // Converts com.mkyong.users.model.User user to
        // org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
        private User buildUserForAuthentication(Users user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
        }

        private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRoles> userRoles) {

            Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

            // Build user's authorities
            for (UserRoles userRole : userRoles) {
                setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
            }

            List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

            return Result;
        }

        public UserDao getUserDao() {
            return userDao;
        }

        public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
            this.userDao = userDao;
        }

    }
@RestController
public class PostAuthController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/userhome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String executeSecurity(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {

        String name = principal.getName();
        model.addAttribute("author", name);
        model.addAttribute("message",
                "Welcome To Login Form Based Spring Security Example!!!");
        return "auth/welcome";

    }
}
```

I am able to login without any issue. But I have one controller with /auth/employee/{id} and request mapping.

Since /auth/** is fullyAuthenticated so how other application can access the rest endpoint

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/auth")
public class EmployeeController{

@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable int id){
    return userDao.getEmployee(id);
}
}
```

Could you please help me how can I access /auth/employee/1001 in another application without login?

**Note:** I am using tiles to render the page in this application

Answer (score 0):

You can use Basic Authentication for this. Extend `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` class and create a custom implementation of it.

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, 
            final HttpServletResponse response, 
            final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Authentication failed, send error response.
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName() + "");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 : " + authException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("MY_TEST_REALM");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

For more info refer [this](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-basic-authentication/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Tharindu. I want to keep the role based authentication to login to the application and access the other urls. And when other application wants to access the rest end point then, it will hit the basic authentication. Could you tell me how to add this basic authentication in **spring-security,xml** file?

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution.

I created a separate api url which will expose only resources and added basic auth filter.

My spring-security.xml looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Oauth start -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>


    <beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="test" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
        <beans:property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="hbUserDetailService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
        <!-- <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="spring_db_DataSource"/>
        </authentication-provider> -->
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <beans:bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <beans:property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </beans:bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
            authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
            authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
            secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <!-- <global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </global-method-security> -->

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

    <!-- Oauth end -->

    <!-- Form based security starts-->                          
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManagerForRest">
        <form-login login-page="/public/login"
            default-target-url="/auth/userhome" authentication-failure-url="/public/fail2login"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/public/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/public/logout" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403.html"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth/**"
            access="fullyAuthenticated" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

        <session-management
            session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" invalid-session-url="/login">
            <concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManagerForRest">
        <authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="hbUserDetailService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- Form based security ends -->
</beans:beans>
```

deploy the project and to get the access token

```
localhost:8080/<context>/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=<uer>&password=<password>
```

it will give the access token using which we can involke the rest end point